# Windows 8 Grouped Items Page no content displayed

Tags: windows-8

in my Windows 8 (Modern UI) App, i want to add a GroupedItemsPage. When I add it as my
main Page, everything Shows up, and the sample data of the template is displayed.
But when i want to add it as an additional page, that i navigate to through my MainPage,
the Content is not displayed. I only see the Title but now Elements at all.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some sample code? You might have mixed something up with the Databinding or the navigation.